# ¿Cómo puedo obtener solo las cifras de un archivo/documento?

Tags: c++, while, fstream

Estoy trabajando en C++ y estoy creando una función que solo obtenga las cifras de dicho documento. Estoy usando `#include <fstream>` para trabajar con archivos. Un ejemplo de información del documento es el siguiente:

```
12/4 7/3
189/5 54/85
```

Me proporciona dos racionales por linea de documento.

El siguiente código es lo que he intentado, pero seguro que hay alguna forma mejor, o que funcione.

```
Racional Racional::FileRacional(std::ifstream file_read) {
    Racional racional;
    auto character;
    int index{1};
    while (!file_read) {
        file_read >> character;
        if (character != '/' || character != ' ') {
            if(ParOImpar(index)) {
                racional.denominador_ = character;
                return racional;
            } else {
                racional.numerador_ = character;
            }
        }
        ++index;
    }
}
```

Mi intención es crear una clase racional que guarde los números en ese formato. Y estoy teniendo problemas en obtener las cifras. No tengo problemas en guardarlos, con un formato sin `/` me funciona.

¿Cómo hago para obtener esos números?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobrecarga los operadores de lectura/escritura en flujo de datos:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const racional &r)
{
    return o << r.numerador << '/' << r.denominador;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, racional &r)
{
    i >> r.numerador;
    // ignoramos la barra, podriamos controlar que realmente hay una barra
    // usando 'peek' https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek
    i.ignore(1);
    i >> r.denominador;
    return i;
}
```

Eso te permitirá tanto guardar como leer de cualquier flujo de datos (consola, archivo, cadena de texto...).

Lo que hace el operador de lectura desde flujo de datos(`<<`) o el de escritura (`>>`) es intentar leer/escribir el tipo de dato facilitado (en este caso el numerador y el denominador son (`int`) enteros) y de no poder hacerlo dejarán el flujo de datos (*stream*) en estado incorrecto.

---

Yo lo he usado con este objeto de prueba:

```
struct racional
{
    int numerador{}, denominador{};

    template <typename coma_flotante>
    operator coma_flotante() const
    {
        static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<coma_flotante>);
        return numerador / static_cast<coma_flotante>(denominador);
    }
};
```

De esta manera:

```
constexpr auto datos = R"(12/4 7/3
189/5 54/85)";

int main()
{

    std::stringstream ss(datos);
    racional r;

    while (ss >> r)
        std::cout << r << " = " << static_cast<double>(r) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Produce [la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##ZZLbTuQwDIavm6ewZiUmFQPdAUYcpvQhuF6pMmkYIrVJlbgLKzSvvsXJFObATdXY8f/9tqP6/kK1aDfj@MtY1Q6NhtK4QF5jV4l9LPwM0b9e1@TRUKiEUM4G0u@9BxzIQYPkAjzC00wur4obuC2uxfLuvljB6qa4W@WztRAsOSgCj8o4i634EJmxBHbotMfG@Y/tAhptXWfs7sg1Gemub5EmvsVOg3Id1i@tI7SkK5G5nuvJ@eOEzCF5FBlzskBIRtUYgvYkAzUPDybEuxy2m7p37KT@Wx5L52uu9JoGb/cuoYBJTGGgkwp54D9Wb8U2Nc64achw9mW3LOVJYrFz/D0hOPN5nNJkwUFZgr/cO@HjvJjvogfgtdiKCWpOoVUljxNm8QNnoKoOOdyHuTQb67yWy9jVdOEI@WXSJHrca4fGyigosoRkIo964oYg05OJct98Hxf@9mpaDTKEBMnT7rhauYFSp/Ez45c2iz@Hm2jc8NzyCnyeBvPHzqPcZOs32xrH/@qlxU0YL1jyUZ2fX@En):

> ```
> 12/4 = 3
> 7/3 = 2.33333
> 189/5 = 37.8
> 54/85 = 0.635294
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido de gran ayuda. Ahora funciona como quería.